# Angular filter: how to get filter complete callback?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am looking for an callback function after $filter filter completes the filtering the data

HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchvalue">
<span ng-click="searchbtn()">Search</span>
```

JS

```
$scope.searchbtn = function() {
  $scope.loading = true;
  $scope.mysearchvalue = $scope.searchvalue;
}
```

When user enters keyword my data will be filtered and i need a callback function after filtering the data.

i have tried using "DOMSubtreeModified" but returning continues logs

```
var myElement = angular.element(document.getElementById("mycontent"));
myElement.bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
  console.log("keep outputting this message");
});
```

[image]

Comment: Why not `$watch` `searchvalue` and `$filter` in controller?

Comment: Hi @MikkoViitala thanks for the reply, can you please explain i have just started angular.

Comment: did you mean 

$scope.items = $filter('filter')($scope.items2, val);

Comment: Yes, more or less.

Answer (score 1):

As said in my comment, why not just use a little delay (debounce) and filter results in controller w/o separate input button. Consider

**HTML template**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <pre ng-bind="filteredData | json"></pre>
  <input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-model-options="{debounce:250}">
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.data = [{text:'aa'},{text:'ab'}];
  $scope.$watch('search', function(val) {
    $scope.filteredData = $filter('filter')($scope.data, val);
  }); 
});
```

---

[image]